# 2 UIImage with adaptive size and one on the second one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller, zposition

I'm trying to add images added as UIImage on a UIView with some constraints.

I have 2 images to put in the same screen.
I would like to fix the first one on the top, the second on the bottom and the 2nd above the 1st one.

I tried to with constraints as I said, also with zPosition. There is always a problem at the bottom. I cannot even see the image.

These images are on a UIView managed by an UIPageViewController.

This is to build a demo of an application with screenshots resized, cut and commented. Please find below some screenshots of my storyboard, my constrains and the result :

[image: Storyboard]
[image: Constraints]
[image: Result]

Please note that the constants of constrains are both equal to 0. 
At the bottom of my result I cannot even see a part of the 2nd image. That's my main problem I think.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What constraints have you tried? Post your code or an explanation of what you did in the storyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your speed ! I've added some screenshots and explanation to my first description.

Comment: My mistake, problem solve with a `imageBottomView.layer.zPosition`. Thank you for looking at my problem.